# How to write a Macro to add a ; to every Line in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, macros

I want to build a macro which adds a `;` to every line end, which hasn't already got one and is not empty or a `{` or `}`.

I use C# in Visual Studio 2010 Professional so I probably need a VB Macro.

I need it because I have to migrate Unittest from VBS to C# (Don't ask why). So I got thousands of lines like foo="53" bazz=1337

I do not care if support is dropped, I should be done in some weeks. Also if there is one `;` put in to much, i still review the code later.

Comment: just.... why? you'd also need to distinguish between *lines*, *statements* and *expressions*... this seems - an odd requirement (LINQ often spans multiple lines, for example)

Comment: So you want to for example change `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)` to  `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i);`?

Comment: FYI: Macros are being removed with Visual Studio 11. I'd maybe re-think how you want to accomplish this (or re-think why you actually need to edit a source code file directly like this).

Comment: regex find&replace can do this. (mostly)

Comment: And what if I do: `int i = 0; int j = 1;` What happens then?

Comment: Really bad idea for a few reasons, as mentioned above you may want things spanning multiple lines but also removing the need to put in ; to terminate lines yourself means you dont get used to doing it.

Comment: `connection.Query(@";[crlf]select * from customers;[crlf]where id = 12345";[crlf]);;`

Comment: Maybe you should rethink -why- you want to do this. What's the issue that underlies this strange requirement? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I need it cause I have to migrate Unittest from VBS to C# (Don't ask why).
So I got thousands of lines like
foo="53"
bazz=1337

I do not care if support is dropped, I should be done in some weeks^^
Also if there is one put in to much, i still review the code later.

Comment: @Purplegoldfish, getting used to writing `;` is **not** a good reason to write `;`. See python.

Comment: @KTB, please edit your question using that additional information so that people don't judge prematurely.

Comment: Seems like a reasonable request right there. Why so many downvotes?

Comment: There are tools out there that might have helped with your code migration. eg http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Comment: @zzzzBov the way he put the original question made it seem like he wanted to do it to avoid having to write ;  since terminating lines with ; is a large part of C# then i would consider it important to get in the habit of doing.  Since this is for a migration tool it does make some more sense now that it is needed.

Comment: @mouters I tried searching for a tool, but i am converting VBS to C# not VB.
I tried the tool you linked already, it does not work with the code.
But thx, anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you've asked for a Macro but a Search and Replace regular expression could be written something like this:

```
Find: {[^\}\{\;]}[ \t]*$
Replace: \1;
```

Visual Studio has good options for to "look in" the current document, current selection, all open documents, and the entire solution...

Comment: +1 for constructive answer, you might want to add that link from the comments too, since it seems helpful to the OP

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are rewriting unittest code from VBS to C# by hand and want to add semicolons automatically. 
I'd say you should rather write a script to convert the VB code to C#; or do it with a search-and-replace (like the regexes mentioned above), then copy the code (or only the relevant parts) into the C# source code.

There's no reason to make it into a macro. Furthemore, bugs like the one mentioned in comments - `for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++);` might be more difficult and/or annoying to find.